# I will have the opportunity or I will get the opportunity

Tags: sentence-meaning, vocabulary

I am confused between because according to google translate translation of both of the sentences are same.

> I will have the opportunity to work with best dancers.

and

> I will get the opportunity to work with best dancers.

Can anyone explain difference between both sentences with understandable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, **To get** an opportunity means the same as **to have** an opportunity, so, **in your example**, both phrases mean the same thing, and they both sound fine.

[To get](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/get) - 
Definition.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer.  "To get" is not the same as "to have", with regard to opportunity or otherwise.  But I agree the essential meaning is the same in this example.

Comment: You're welcome, I should've emphasized it a little bit more by making it clear right from the beginning of the sentence. Thanks for bringing it up to attention I'll do better next time.